# Jibun "myself" or "I"?

Tags: meaning, translation

> 俺はそこで初めて自分が何を知らないかを知ることができたんだ

Is it "out there I knew for the first time what I didn't know about myself" or "I knew what I didn't know"?

Answer (score 2):

It's "what I didn't know". 自分 is marked with the subject marker が, which means 自分 is the subject of 知る ("to know"). Nothing in your sentence corresponds to "about myself".

自分 is a pronoun that can be rendered as "I", "you", "he/she", "myself", "yourself", or "himself/herself" depending on the context, but here it's just "I" except that it's slightly emphatic. You may use "I myself" instead of "I" if you think it's suitable in the context.